# Find a parametric equation of a plane curve

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, curvature, differential, plane-curves

**The task is to find a parametric equation of a curve, if you are given its curvature in arclength parametrisation.** I know that I need to integrate but I don’t get the idea of angle theta(what’s it?) and plus there are constants of integration.

Would be very grateful if someone explained how to solve it.

For example:

$$k(s)=\frac1{as\sqrt2}, \text{where }a=\text{constant}$$